# Try to connect to a server with Google Assistance App

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tcp, actions-on-google

I need to send data out from my google assistance app to a database. In order to do this, I've created a server that takes the data, packages it, and then sends it out. I have the hostname and port and it works in a normal javascript/node.js program but when I use it in my google assistant app nothing happens. I tried figuring out the problem and it looks like the code just isn't connecting. The code I'm using to send data to the server is as follows:

```
    function sendData(app){
        var net = require('net');
        var message = {"test": 200};
        var thisMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
        var client = new net.Socket();
        client.connect(<port>, '<hostname>', function() {
          app.tell(JSON.stringify(client.address()));
          console.log('Connected');
          client.write(thisMessage);
        });


        client.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('Received: ' + data);
          client.destroy();
        });

        client.on('close', function() {
          console.log('Connection closed');
        });
        return 0;
       }
```

(NOTE: Port and hostname left out for privacy purposes)

This completely skips over the app.tell, leading me to believe the connection is never made. I know it works asynchronously with the server, however, I don't understand why it isn't connecting whatsoever. 
I have tried it both in simulation and on my smartphone with sandbox on and off. Is there a better way to connect? Note that the server I'm connecting to is python-based.

Comment: Where are you running the javascript/node.js code? Google Cloud Functions or Google Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Comment: I am using the Actions SDK from actions on google, which requires and action.json package. That only takes a function URL for the code, which is created by using firebase's "functions.https.onRequest". However, outside of that I'm pretty sure google cloud functions for firebase can't be used unfortunately (although I would be glad to be mistaken)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you're running it on Cloud Functions for Firebase which has a [limit on outbound connections](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) under their free "Spark" plan. With this plan, you can only connect to other Google services. This is usually a good way to start understanding how to handle Action requests, but has limitations. To access endpoints outside of Google, you need to upgrade to either their "Flame" fixed price plan or "Blaze" pay-as-you-go plan.

You do not, however, need to run on Google's servers or need to use node.js. All you need is a public HTTPS server with a valid SSL cert. If you are familiar with JSON, you can use any programming language to handle the request and response. If you are familiar with node.js, you just need a node.js server that can create Express request and response objects.